# Xamarin Entry got Focused if removed and added to a parent view. why it is happening?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.entry

In our application we add and remove an entry from view hierarchy for addressing some business logic. But by doing so we encountered an undesired behaviour which focus the entry again on adding to the view hierarchy

Do anybody have encountered that behaviour before and have any fix for this issue?

FYI:- I tried to fix this issue by disabling that entry before removing from view and enabling that entry after adding to the view hierarchy But it fixed only on iOS not in android.

Comment: Are you removing the Entry when it has focus? and then adding it back?

Comment: @G.hakim No it is not focused at the time of removing

Comment: Then after adding the entry back just focus the main layout that should work use the focus method for viewrenderer

Comment: @G.hakim Are u saying that the Entry will get unfocused if I focus the main  layout?

Comment: Well of course it will isn't that the purpose of the focus method